# Values of Buttons Not Updating Properly

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have an integer `ArrayList` and several buttons. Each button corresponds to an index of the `ArrayList` and I want to display the value of each button's corresponding index as its text. I have everything working with button behavior, etc. The problem is when I go to swap a button's value (index value) with another it will start to display 0s for every value I swap it with. I am always going to be swapping the 0 with something else.

So if I have buttons: b1, b2, b3 with values 0, 1, 2 respectively and I swap the values of b1 and b2. The result becomes 0, 0, 2. This is the swapping function:

```
public static void swap(ArrayList<Integer> list, int firstInd, int secondInd) {
    int temp = list.get(firstInd);
    list.set(firstInd, list.get(secondInd));
    list.set(secondInd, temp);
}
```

This swap method works, I have tested it independently using print statements, etc. and there are no duplicate 0s and all of the rest of the numbers remain in the list.

Here is the relevant code:

```
// class declaration
static ArrayList<Integer> numList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

// onCreate
// initialize ArrayList
// displays initial values on buttons

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.first: {
            switchButtonValues(R.id.first);
            b1.setText(String.valueOf(numList.get(0)));
            updateButtonStates();
            break;
        }
        case R.id.second: {
            switchButtonValues(R.id.second);
            b2.setText(String.valueOf(numList.get(1)));
            updateButtonStates();
            break;
        }
// etc for all buttons

public static void switchButtonValues(int buttonNum) {
    switch(buttonNum) {
        case R.id.first: {
            if(numList.get(1) == 0) {
                swap(numList, 0, 1);
            } else if (numList.get(3) == 0) {
                swap(numList, 0, 3);
            } else {

            }

            break;
        }
        case R.id.second: {
// etc. for the buttons
```

The buttons displaying the initial values is correct. So I know the ArrayList is getting initialized properly. The problem occurs when the swapping occurs. All of the values are getting overwritten with 0 somehow.

Even though 0s are overwriting the other values, the button behavior is working correctly because it knows where the "real" 0 is. I have cleaned the project too.

Why is this happening? Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What does `updateButtonStates();` do?

Comment: @Nick All that does is set the enabled state of the buttons, allowing which ones can be clicked. -buttonName.setEnabled(boolean); for each one

Comment: The behavior of the buttons work properly, because even though a bunch of 0s are overwriting the other numbers, it knows where the "real" 0 is.

Comment: Why you don't change for ToggleButton, and select one button and check in the array of ToggleButtons what is selected, if you have only one don't do nothing, if you have two selected you swap them then you deselect both toggles...

Comment: @WilliamBertan That sounds more complicated than what I have. I also have all of the swapping stuff written out, but for some reason it is like it is not getting refreshed or something. The way I have it coded now is wherever the 0 is, its neighboring buttons are enabled through buttonName.setEnabled(true); so you just have to click on the neighbor that you want to swap the 0 with. The issue I am having is not with the swapping itself, but why everything that is being swapped is being shown as a 0 and not the number the 0 is being swapped with (but it knows where the "real" 0 is.

Comment: @WilliamBertan So for example if you have a 2x2 grid with values (reading across row 1 and then row 2): 0, 1 / 2, 3 You decide to swap the 0 and the 1, it then becomes 0, 0 / 2, 3. Then you swap the upper right 0 (the real 0) with the 3 in the lower right and it becomes: 0, 0 / 2, 0 ... it always knows where the 0 is supposed to be, but all of the other numbers are being displayed as 0 as well, even though the swapping function works and I am setting the button text to arrayList.get(index);

Comment: I'm not in home now, but tonight I will try do an app with the behavior you described and using buttons, I hope tomorrow I post some news.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did an example, I hope it's near what you expect:

```
package br.com.bertan.swap.buttons;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class SwapButtonsActivity extends Activity {

    // class declaration
    static ArrayList<Integer> numList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    static ArrayList<Button> btnList = new ArrayList<Button>();

    public static void swap(ArrayList<Integer> list, int firstInd, int secondInd) {
        int temp = list.get(firstInd);
        list.set(firstInd, list.get(secondInd));
        list.set(secondInd, temp);
    }

    private void updateButtonStates(){

        int index_0 = -1;

        int index_up = -1;
        int index_down = -1;
        int index_left = -1;
        int index_right = -1;

        for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++){
            if(index_0 >= 0){   
                if(i != index_up
                   && i != index_down
                   && i != index_left
                   && i != index_right
//                 && i != index_0
                   ){
                    btnList.get(i).setEnabled(false);
                } else {
                    btnList.get(i).setEnabled(true);
                }
            } else {
                if(numList.get(i) == 0){
                    index_0 = i;

                    if(index_0 > 3){
                        index_up = index_0 - 4;
                    }

                    if(index_0 < 12){
                        index_down = index_0 + 4;
                    }

                    if(index_0 != 0
                       && index_0 != 4
                       && index_0 != 8
                       && index_0 != 12){
                        index_left = index_0 - 1;
                    }

                    if(index_0 != 3
                       && index_0 != 7
                       && index_0 != 11
                       && index_0 != 15){
                        index_right = index_0 + 1;
                    }

                    i = -1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void switchButtonValues(int buttonNum) {
        int index_0 = -1;
        int index_btn = -1;

        for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++){
            if(index_0 < 0){
                if(numList.get(i) == 0){
                    index_0 = i;
                }
            }

            if(index_btn < 0){
                if(buttonNum == btnList.get(i).getId()){
                    index_btn = i;
                }
            }

            if(index_0 >= 0 && index_btn >=0){
                break;
            }
        }

        btnList.get(index_0).setText(btnList.get(index_btn).getText().toString());
        btnList.get(index_btn).setText("0");

        numList.set(index_0, numList.get(index_btn));
        numList.set(index_btn, 0);
    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // initialize ArrayList
        for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++){
            numList.add(i);
        }

        final Button btn_01 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_01);
        final Button btn_02 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_02);
        final Button btn_03 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_03);
        final Button btn_04 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_04);
        final Button btn_05 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_05);
        final Button btn_06 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_06);
        final Button btn_07 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_07);
        final Button btn_08 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_08);
        final Button btn_09 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_09);
        final Button btn_10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_10);
        final Button btn_11 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_11);
        final Button btn_12 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_12);
        final Button btn_13 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_13);
        final Button btn_14 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_14);
        final Button btn_15 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_15);
        final Button btn_16 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_16);

        btnList.add(btn_01);
        btnList.add(btn_02);
        btnList.add(btn_03);
        btnList.add(btn_04);
        btnList.add(btn_05);
        btnList.add(btn_06);
        btnList.add(btn_07);
        btnList.add(btn_08);
        btnList.add(btn_09);
        btnList.add(btn_10);
        btnList.add(btn_11);
        btnList.add(btn_12);
        btnList.add(btn_13);
        btnList.add(btn_14);
        btnList.add(btn_15);
        btnList.add(btn_16);

        OnClickListener click_listener = new OnClickListener() {            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch(v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.btn_01: {
                        switchButtonValues(R.id.btn_01);
                        btn_01.setText(String.valueOf(numList.get(0)));
                        updateButtonStates();
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.btn_02: {
                        switchButtonValues(R.id.btn_02);
                        btn_02.setText(String.valueOf(numList.get(1)));
                        updateButtonStates();
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.btn_03: {
                        switchButtonValues(R.id.btn_03);
                        btn_03.setText(String.valueOf(numList.get(2)));
                        updateButtonStates();
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.btn_04: {
                        switchButtonValues(R.id.btn_04);
                        btn_04.setText(String.valueOf(numList.get(3)));
                        updateButtonStates();
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.btn_05: {
                        switchButtonValues(R.id.btn_05);
                        btn_05.setText(String.valueOf(numList.get(4)));
                        updateButtonStates();
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.btn_06: {
                        switchButtonValues(R.id.btn_06);
                        btn_06.setText(String.valueOf(numList.get(5)));
                        updateButtonStates();
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.btn_07: {
                        switchButtonValues(R.id.btn_07);
                        btn_07.setText(String.valueOf(numList.get(6)));
                        updateButtonStates();
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.btn_08: {
                        switchButtonValues(R.id.btn_08);
                        btn_08.setText(String.valueOf(numList.get(7)));
                        updateButtonStates();
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.btn_09: {
                        switchButtonValues(R.id.btn_09);
                        btn_09.setText(String.valueOf(numList.get(8)));
                        updateButtonStates();
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.btn_10: {
                        switchButtonValues(R.id.btn_10);
                        btn_10.setText(String.valueOf(numList.get(9)));
                        updateButtonStates();
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.btn_11: {
                        switchButtonValues(R.id.btn_11);
                        btn_11.setText(String.valueOf(numList.get(10)));
                        updateButtonStates();
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.btn_12: {
                        switchButtonValues(R.id.btn_12);
                        btn_12.setText(String.valueOf(numList.get(11)));
                        updateButtonStates();
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.btn_13: {
                        switchButtonValues(R.id.btn_13);
                        btn_13.setText(String.valueOf(numList.get(12)));
                        updateButtonStates();
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.btn_14: {
                        switchButtonValues(R.id.btn_14);
                        btn_14.setText(String.valueOf(numList.get(13)));
                        updateButtonStates();
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.btn_15: {
                        switchButtonValues(R.id.btn_15);
                        btn_15.setText(String.valueOf(numList.get(14)));
                        updateButtonStates();
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.btn_16: {
                        switchButtonValues(R.id.btn_16);
                        btn_16.setText(String.valueOf(numList.get(15)));
                        updateButtonStates();
                        break;
                    }
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        };

        // displays initial values on buttons
        for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++){
            btnList.get(i).setText(String.valueOf(numList.get(i)));
            btnList.get(i).setOnClickListener(click_listener);
        }

        updateButtonStates();
    }
}
```

And here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
    <TableLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TableRow 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/btn_01"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="0"
                android:textSize="50dip"
                android:textStyle="bold"
            />
            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/btn_02"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="1"
                android:textSize="50dip"
                android:textStyle="bold"
            />
            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/btn_03"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="2"
                android:textSize="50dip"
                android:textStyle="bold"
            />
            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/btn_04"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="3"
                android:textSize="50dip"
                android:textStyle="bold"
            />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/btn_05"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="4"
                android:textSize="50dip"
                android:textStyle="bold"
            />
            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/btn_06"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="5"
                android:textSize="50dip"
                android:textStyle="bold"
            />
            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/btn_07"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="6"
                android:textSize="50dip"
                android:textStyle="bold"
            />
            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/btn_08"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="7"
                android:textSize="50dip"
                android:textStyle="bold"
            />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/btn_09"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="8"
                android:textSize="50dip"
                android:textStyle="bold"
            />
            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/btn_10"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="9"
                android:textSize="50dip"
                android:textStyle="bold"
            />
            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/btn_11"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="10"
                android:textSize="50dip"
                android:textStyle="bold"
            />
            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/btn_12"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="11"
                android:textSize="50dip"
                android:textStyle="bold"
            />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/btn_13"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="12"
                android:textSize="50dip"
                android:textStyle="bold"
            />
            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/btn_14"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="13"
                android:textSize="50dip"
                android:textStyle="bold"
            />
            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/btn_15"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="14"
                android:textSize="50dip"
                android:textStyle="bold"
            />
            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/btn_16"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="15"
                android:textSize="50dip"
                android:textStyle="bold"
            />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

that's worked just fine, and really quite a funny when you shuffle the places and try to put then in order... hehehe

It's simple and was one good idea for a game :D (I will do some sort of this genre and let see what happens)

I think that's possible to better the code, I had suspect of this part of your code:

```
case R.id.btn_01: {
    switchButtonValues(R.id.btn_01);
    btn_01.setText(String.valueOf(numList.get(0)));
    updateButtonStates();
    break;
}
```

I thinked you switch the values, and next set the text with the numList value of that position, but, you had changed with the 0, isn't? Maybe it's your problem, try put the line that set the text before the switch...

cya,
Bertan.

Comment: Ohhh...wait...I think I had a revelation spurred by the very last part of your answer. I am going to try it out. I am only setting the value of one of the buttons based on the one button clicked on the switch statement. I need to update all of the buttons every time, no matter what button is clicked. I am going to try changing that so they all are updated...

Comment: *facepalm* That was the whole problem. I needed to update the values of every button whenever a button was clicked, so I wrote a method to do that. So I'll accept your answer for inspiring that thought and because no one else has answered.